# Last Execution Time and Next Execution Time Not correct

Tags: c#, quartz-scheduler, quartz.net

I am using Quartz.net.

I have configure job with attribute DisallowConcurrentExecution. I want single instance of that job execute.

I have configured trigger that fire every 10 seconds but in some situation my job get more than minutes to complete. Once this happen I can not see Last Execution Time and Next execution correct. It still refer to old time.

I am new to quartz but I know that thread pool might schedule job that in queue and when one instance complete and new will get start because of attribute configuration but why it is not maintaining time of execution properly.

Please help.

Answer (score 3):

Double-posted here: https://github.com/quartznet/quartznet/issues/173

> This works as designed. Quartz considers your trigger misfired as it
>   didn't run when it was supposed to (job's concurrent execution
>   protection prohibited it). You need to tweak your misfire handling
>   configuration.

http://www.quartz-scheduler.net/documentation/quartz-2.x/tutorial/more-about-triggers.html

Comment: It means it is last run time of Trigger. I thought that It is consider when job actually executed for that trigger. As I am new to this I might have to look for JobListener for my purpose. I want actual time job is executed last time. I simply want to ignore trigger if it fire during scheduler is stop or job already executed.